# Setting cookies with jQuery retrieving with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to set a cookie with jQuery on SUCCESS and retrieve it with PHP
My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        tid: '.$testID.',
        do:"'.$do.'"
    },
    success: function( html ) {
        $("#partBox").html( html ); 
        var hgt = Math.ceil(($("#partBox").height() - 31) / 2); 
        $.cookie("partBoxH", hgt);
    }
});
```

and my PHP:

```
isset($_COOKIE['partBoxH']) ? $_COOKIE['partBoxH'] : '50'
```

it does not seem to work for some reason... Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi can you provide some live code or the live page that the AJAX is called?

Comment: May bad. This code ($.cookie...) requires a plug-in which I did not include...

Answer (score 0):

First set the cookie after that do the AJAX call, like that:

```
$.cookie("partBoxH", hgt);
```

than do AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        tid: '<?php echo $testID;?>',
        do:"'<?php echo $do;?>'"
    },
    success: function( html ) {
        $("#partBox").html( html ); 
    }
});
```

Comment: hgt is a height of the #partBox and I can only get it after the $("#partBox").html( html ); is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Is the php code located in the file ajax.php?...
In his case you are setting up the cookie after the ajax call (on success).

Comment: Yes, I need it after, to be used on the following AJAX calls, not the first one. They have to do with paging results and I can only determine the height of the area after the first AJAX call is successful.